# Interaction between IMessageSession and TransactionScope

Tags: azureservicebus, nservicebus

I have an `IMessageSession` and I would like to know if it's possible to make sending/publishing messages part of a transaction? e.g. would the following work?

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
  // Some task that may or may not succeed
  
  await _messageSession.Send(new Message());
  scope.Complete();
}
```

From what I can tell the message is sent immediately, and sometimes the completion of the transaction is still happening while the message is being handled - so if it is possible then what I'm doing above is wrong.

It's part of a web page, so I don't have access to an `IMessageHandlerContext` where the above code works as expected

Answer (score 0):

That depends on if the transport selected supports transaction scopes. In general it is not advised to do this.

Did you consider sending a single message and have all relevant logic processed in a handler outside of the webpage/website?

Answer (score 0):

The default .NET behavior is that a TransactionScope does NOT flow with async code.  In order to let your TransactionScope flow with async code, you need to create it as follows:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
  // Some task that may or may not succeed
  
  await _messageSession.Send(new Message());
  scope.Complete();
}
```

Particular has a nice [Blog Post](https://particular.net/blog/transactionscope-and-async-await-be-one-with-the-flow) about this.

But there is no need to create a transactionscope yourself in your handlers.  You can configure NServiceBus to automatically wrap all your message handlers in a TransactionScope via configuration, like this:

```
endpointConfiguration.UnitOfWork().WrapHandlersInATransactionScope();
```

See the [NServiceBus UnitOfWork Documentation](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/pipeline/unit-of-work) for more information.